# Golang: limit concurrency levels of a blocking operation

Tags: go

I have the following scenario:
I am receiving a message on a channel telling me to upload a file. The upload is made by the blocking function `uploadToServer`. The `zipGen` channel may receive several messages per second, and I want to upload maximum 5 files simultaneously (not more, but possibly less - depending on how many messages are sent on `zipGen` by a third worker that is out of the scope of this question).

The `listenToZips` function runs inside a go routine (`go listenToZips()` on the file's `init` function):

```
func listenToZips() {
    for {
        select {
        case zip := <-zipGen:
          uploadToServer(zip) // this is blocking
        }
    }
}
```

If I launch `go uploadToServer(zip)` instead of just `uploadToServer(zip)` - I get too much concurrency (so for example my program will try to upload 10 files at the same time, but I want a maximum of 5).

On the other hand, without `go uploadToServer(zip)` (just using `uploadToServer(zip)` like in the above function), I only upload one file at a time (since the `uploadToServer(zip)` is blocking).

How can I achieve this level of control to allow me a max upload of 5 files simultaneously?

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, if you only have a single `case` within the `select` (including no `default` case) then your whole loop is almost exactly the same as the simplified: `for zip := range zipGen { uploadToServer(zip) }`. (The one difference is that the simplified version handles the channel closing much better; your code would busy loop calling `uploadToServer(nil)` as quickly as it can if the channel closed).

Comment: @DaveC thanks for spotting this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest option - prespawn N goroutines that take input from the channel, and upload it, in a loop. In each goroutine's context the operation will be blocking, but N goroutines do this. Only one goroutine will receive each message, of course.

```
func listenToZips(concurrent int) {

    for i:=0; i < concurrent; i++ {

      // spawn a listener goroutine
      go func() {

         for {
            select {
            case zip := <-zipGen:
               uploadToServer(zip) // this is blocking
            }
         }
      }()

   }

}
```

Of course you can then add stop condition, probably using a different channel, but the basic idea is just the same.

Comment: I like simple. Thanks!

Comment: @orcaman I'm using a more complicated pattern when the limit is very big, and the required concurrency might change, so I don't want to run a constant number of goroutines if most of them are idle. But in small numbers this is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

try this: 
https://github.com/korovkin/limiter

```
 limiter := NewConcurrencyLimiter(10)
 limiter.Execute(func() {
        uploadToServer()
 })
 limiter.Wait()
```